# Should I aquire largest size of image if it's free?

Tags: images

If I can get an image in any size I want (for FREE), but only ONE size/format of each image, would it be wise of me to get it in the largest vector/scalable (eps) size? Wondering if it's an issue at all when converting to other formats or downsizing. Seems that I would be wise to get it in the largest size possible then downsize as needed (and change to whatever format is best: PNG, smaller jpg, etc.).

Is that correct?

Comment: All vector files are infinitely scalable. Size really only matters for raster... and in that case, yes.

Comment: To elaborate on Scott's point, providing it is a vector .eps/.ai without any rasterized images embedded within, you could put that on the side of a building. Rasterized images such as jpeg/png will only be good for as big as you source them.

Answer (score 3):

This is correct for **bitmap** images. For them, you should always try to get the biggest version. You can always make it smaller, but you can't do the opposite if you start with a small sample.

But as Scott mentions in the comments, this is not a problem with vectors. Vectors are scalable regardless of their 'original' size, because they use paths (or strokes) which lead through locations called control points. What's important is the relationship between all of these elements, so size is not a problem.

[image]

<sub>Source of image: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_graphics)</sub>